# Survey web app that tracks responses over time (i.e. Longitudinal surveys)

Tags: web-apps, survey

I want to build a survey. I'm thinking of tools like [Google Forms](https://www.google.com/forms/about/) or [Typeform](https://www.typeform.com/).

However, I need to track, overtime, the evolution of the answers of the survey... I.e. in the first batch the answers were X; in the second batch of days the answer were Y... and I want to have graphics that track the evolution of the answers overtime.

Are there web apps that allow me to do this? (I think Google/ Typeform don't offer this.)